# How to combine bazel aspects and cc_library

Tags: bazel, bazel-aspect

I want to build a rule that is very similar to `cc_proto_library`. The key features are that it would apply an aspect to all the transitive `proto_library` dependencies and generate `.cc` and `.h` files for all of the dependencies. In addition it would generate actions that would compile these into object files.

While I understand how I can do the file generation, I don't see how to easily do the object generation. The [native](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/native.html#modules.native) module is not available for rule (or aspect) implementations, and I cannot use a macro on top of the aspect as I need the object files to be generated in the same package as the `proto_library` so that it is generated only once.

`cc_proto_library` can do this I believe because it is not written in Skylark and thus has access to more primitives. Is there anyway to do this with just Skylark?

Comment: I asked our Skylark+C++ person to comment on creating C++ compile actions from Skylark, but just a quick reply - if you ever will use `native.cc_proto_library` in the same project, take care to make your rule generate different file names and different symbols. Otherwise, you'll run into output file conflicts and linker errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately currently not possible. There is no Skylark API to the C++ rules/actions (what we call [C++ sandwich](https://bazel.build/designs/2016/08/04/extensibility-for-native-rules.html)). We have plans to implement this in Q1 2018. There are many tracking issues, this one looks the most relevant: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2163.